# How can I fix wp_insert_comment failure when 'comment_content" includes slanted apostrophe in Excel csv source data

Tags: comments

For the purpose of transferring a very large number of user responses from non-WordPress to WordPress comments, I've been given a Google Sheet. Regardless of the method by which I turn the Sheet into a CSV file (direct download as CSV, download as xlsx then save as csv, copy-paste into Excel and save), I get some version of the same problem, though with marginally varying results.

1. If processed as saved, comments with slanted apostrophes/curled single quotes - `’` - are simply not inserted - they do not appear either in backend comments.php or in the post output.
2. If I use esc_html() on the comment content, the comments will be processed - are will be listed in the backend and in post output - but the comment content **will be emptied**.
3. I've tried some other means to change the comment content programmatically, like str_replace-ing `’` with `'`, but I haven't had any luck with that: The affected comments are still rejected.
4. Other shots in the dark investigated so for, like disabling wp_texturize() via filter function, have no effect.

**The one method that has worked so far has been to run a straight character replace - `’` with `'` - in the data files before saving as CSV and uploading**. That's sub-optimal for large files that will in the future need to be updated continually, and I can't shake the feeling that there *should* be a possibly very simple programmatic solution.

First, here's the relevant portion of the code I'm using for the function, which I'm running via shortcode, up to the point where comment_data is initially set. FYI the post_id is added later. (Per request, I'll add more of the code - which also inserts posts and categories, at the end.)

```
    $new_array = array() ;
     
    if ( ( $handle = fopen( __DIR__ . "/sample_data.csv", "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        
        while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle ) ) !== FALSE ) { 
         
            $new_array[] = $data ; 
            
        }
        
        fclose( $handle ) ;
        
    }
    
    foreach( $new_array as $insert_array ) {
        
        $comment_data = array(
            
            'comment_author'    =>  $insert_array[0] , 
            'comment_content'   =>  $insert_array[4] , //a string, see notes
            'comment_date'      =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $insert_array[5] ) ),   
            'comment_date_gmt'  =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $insert_array[5] ) ), 
    
        ) ; 

    }
```

To re-state the issue: If I don't make any other changes, then the implicated entries simply do not get added at all, while the rest of the file/rows are completed, and entries that use straight quotes are included in the output, as expected.

FOR CLARIFICATION, RE QUESTIONS/REQUESTS

Each row is extracted from the csv file as an array, with each cell as a value. The highlighted cells below are two typical comment content cells - extracted as successive `$insert_array[4]`'s. The first one transfers/outputs just fine. The second one, with a slanty single quote in the second sentence produces the issues I've described. Cells with straight quotes transfer fine.

[image: Leveriza Abu Dhabi NONE United Arab Emirates Abu Dhabi is one of the safest cities in the world. It is the capital of a developed country, which is the United Arab Emirates. The people/locals have a deep respect for their religion and culture herein. Abu Dhabi is a great place to visit or to reside for employment purposes. 8/5/2020 6:49:25 413912 Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates Malak Abu Dhabi NONE United Arab Emirates Abu Dhabi is the capital of the UAE. It’s a very diverse city with a lot of beautiful places. It’s one of the wealthiest cities in the country, so it’s considered an expensive city. Compared to Dubai, it’s a more traditional city that has a lot to offer in terms of luxury. 8/8/2020 16:57:23 415450 Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates]

Full code:

```
add_shortcode( 'insert_from_db_file', 'insert_from_db_file_handler' ) ;

function insert_from_db_file_handler( $atts ) { 
    
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');
    
    $a  = shortcode_atts( array( 
    
        'test'=> 'on',
        
        ), $atts ) ;
    
    $new_array = array() ;
     
    if ( ( $handle = fopen( __DIR__ . "/sample_data.csv", "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        
        while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle ) ) !== FALSE ) { 
         
            $new_array[] = $data ; 
            
        }
        
        fclose( $handle ) ;
        
    }

    $i = 0 ;
    
    
    foreach( $new_array as $insert_array ) {
        
        $cats = array() ;
        $state_id = $country_id = $state = $country = $post_id = '' ;
        
        $i++ ;
        
        if ( 'on' == $a['test'] && $i > 300 ) {
            
            break ; 
            
        }
        
        $comment_data = array(
            
            'comment_author'    =>  $insert_array[0] ,
            'comment_content'   =>  $insert_array[4] ,
            'comment_date'      =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $insert_array[5] ) ),   
            'comment_date_gmt'  =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $insert_array[5] ) ),
            'comment_post_id'   =>  '',
            'comment_meta'      => array(
            
                'db_row'    => $insert_array[6],
                'standardized_location' =>  $insert_array[7],
        
            ), 
    
        ) ;  
        
        if ( ! get_page_by_title( $insert_array[1], OBJECT, 'city' ) ) {  // don't create new post if already exists
                
            //create city categories 
            $country    =   'NONE' == $insert_array[3] ? '' : ucfirst( $insert_array[3] ) ;
            $state      =   'NONE' == $insert_array[2] ? '' : ucfirst( $insert_array[2] ) ; //some lowercase in db
            
            $country_id =   wp_create_category( $country ) ; 
            $cats[]     =   $country_id ;
        
            if ( $state ) {
                
                $state_id   = wp_create_category( $state, $country_id ) ; 
                $cats[]     = $state_id ;
                
            } 
            
            //create post
            $post_arr = array( 
            
                'post_title'        => ucfirst( $insert_array[1] ), //lowercase in some data
                'post_content'      => $insert_array[1],
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'post_author'       => 3,
                'comment_status'    => 'closed',
                'post_category'     =>  $cats,
                'post_type'         =>  'city'
            
            ) ;  
        
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_arr ) ; 
            $args = array( 
            
                'post_id' => $post_id,
                'count' => true, 
                
            ) ;
            $previous_comment = get_comments( $args ) ;
            
            $comment_data['comment_post_ID'] = $post_id ; 
            //add unique comments only
            
            if ( ! $previous_comment ) {
                
                $comment = wp_insert_comment( $comment_data ) ;
                if ( ! $comment ) {
                    
                    custom_logs( 'FALSE FOR ' . $i ) ;
                    custom_logs( print_r( $insert_array, true ) ) ;
                    
                }
            
            }
            
            $cities[] = $insert_array[1] ;
            
            
        } else { //find city for comments
        
            $db_rows = array() ; // don't accumulate gigantic db_rows?
            
            $id = get_page_by_title( $insert_array[1], OBJECT, 'city' )->ID ;
            
            $args = array( 
            
                'post_id' => $id, 
                
            ) ;

            $previous_comments = get_comments( $args ) ;
            
            foreach ( $previous_comments as $previous_comment ) {
                
                $db_rows[] = get_comment_meta( $previous_comment->comment_ID, 'db_row', true ) ; 
                
            }
            
            if ( $previous_comments && ! in_array( $insert_array[6], $db_rows ) ) { 
            
                $comment_data['comment_post_ID'] = $id ;  
                 
                $comment = wp_insert_comment( $comment_data ) ;
                
                if ( ! $comment ) {
                    
                    custom_logs( 'FALSE FOR ' . $i ) ; //"custom_logs( $message )" is a utility function for debugging
                    custom_logs( print_r( $insert_array, true ) ) ;
                    
                }
             
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    return $i . 'COMMENTS INSERTED' ; 
    
}
```

Comment: I see `comment_data` is defined as an array, but  I don't see where you insert  the comment? I'm also not sure why you use 2  loops, it  will increase memory consumption  and put an upper bounds on the size of the CSV

Comment: Also can you include  2 sample lines? One that works and one that does not? It's difficult to imagine what you're describing

Comment: Thanks, will clarify.

Comment: Thanks, can you update the code too? It's incomplete, there is no `wp_insert_comment` call in your question, try not to hide code as it's unhelpful, context is important

Comment: I thought it would just be distracting, but will update that, too - a bit later...

Comment: It's best to give too much information :) Especially if it helps other people reproduce it locally, sometimes it reveals an entirely new easier method or unrelated but critical mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If processed as saved, comments with slanted apostrophes/curled single
> quotes - `’` - are simply not inserted - they do not appear either in
> backend comments.php or in the post output.

That's because the `wpdb` class [checks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/strip_invalid_text/) if the comment content contains any invalid (UTF-8) text, and if yes, then `wpdb` rejects the content and therefore does not run the insert query (which originates from `wp_insert_comment()`).

> If I use esc_html() on the comment content, the comments will be
> processed - are will be listed in the backend and in post output - but
> the comment content **will be emptied**.

Similar to the first case above, where `esc_html()` uses [`wp_check_invalid_utf8()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_invalid_utf8/) to check if the comment content contains any invalid UTF-8 text, and if so, then an empty string is returned (by default).

> I've tried some other means to change the comment content
> programmatically, like str_replace-ing `’` with `'`, but I haven't had
> any luck with that: The affected comments are still rejected.

Yes, because the slanted quote you passed to `str_replace()` isn't the same slanted quote in the comment content, i.e. their encoding does not match, only their appearance that looks alike.

### Therefore... You may simply need to convert the file encoding to UTF-8.

And I mean, convert it before uploading the file. :) Have you already tried doing so?

Or if you're using Windows, then you should know that MS Excel by default saves the CSV file using the ANSI ( i.e. Windows-1252 or Western European (Windows) ) encoding, so you should instead [save it as UTF-8](https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-save-csv-excel-file-as-utf-8-encoded/#save-csv-microsoft-excel) — in the "Save As" window, click the "Tools" next to the "Save" button, select "Web Options", then go to the "Encoding" tab and choose "Unicode (UTF-8)".

> Regardless of the method by which I turn the Sheet into a CSV file
> (direct download as CSV, download as xlsx then save as csv, copy-paste
> into Excel and save), I get some version of the same problem

- If by the "direct download as CSV", you mean the *File → Download → "Comma-separated values (.csv, current sheet)"* option in the Google Sheets (web) app, then perhaps after you downloaded the file, you edited it and saved it using MS Excel (with the encoding set to the default)?
- Because Google Sheets actually encodes the sheet in UTF-8 (when exporting the sheet for download), so if you uploaded the file as-is (without editing it) to your website, then you wouldn't have the encoding issues.

And if you want to be sure the encoding is Windows-1252, then try one of these (with the already-uploaded data), where if the encoding is indeed Windows-1252, then the 2nd and 3rd below would give you the slanted quote as-is (i.e. just as how it appears on-screen — `’`), whereas the first one would give you `&rsquo;` ( and not the `&#2013266066;`.. ).

- `$comment_content = mb_convert_encoding( $insert_array[4], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'Windows-1252' );`
- `$comment_content = mb_convert_encoding( $insert_array[4], 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252' );`
- `$comment_content = iconv( 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $insert_array[4] );`

Or actually, if you use Notepad++, then you could easily check the encoding by looking at the bottom-right corner of the editor. :)

### UPDATE

- Actually, when I said save it as UTF-8, I mean, in Google Sheets, export the file as an Excel file (.xlsx) and then in Excel, export it as CSV with the UTF-8 encoding. Have you tried doing so or is that what you actually did?
- And if `wp_insert_category()` works, but not [`wp_create_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_category/), then it's likely that [`category_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_exists/) fails and it could be due to many reasons...

But anyway, now that you know what the file encoding is (which is Windows-1252), then if you just can't get the CSV data to work without giving you the encoding (or invalid characters) issues, then you can try to manually encode the data (i.e. each item in `$insert_array`) to UTF-8 like so:

```php
function my_fix_invalid_utf8( $text ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'iconv' ) ) {
        return iconv( 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $text );
    } elseif ( function_exists( 'mb_convert_encoding' ) ) {
        return mb_convert_encoding( $text, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252' );
    } elseif ( function_exists( 'utf8_encode' ) ) {
        // This would not fix the APPEARANCE of the text (i.e. you'd see something like '??' on
        // the page), but this would at least let you insert the comment or text to the database..
        return utf8_encode( $text );
    }

    return $text; // if all else fails, return the text as-is
}

$insert_array = array_map( 'my_fix_invalid_utf8', $insert_array );
```

And I have no affiliations with the author/devs of Notepad++, but you could actually *easily* convert the encoding using Notepad++.. so give it a try? :) <sup>(the below file was BTW, exported from an Excel file)</sup>

[image: Easily convert file encoding using Notepad++ — Preview in a Windowws 10 computer]

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going through your alternatives one by one. First one didn't help, but I'm far from giving up hope.

Comment: Success on second alternative: Direct dl of Google Sheet as CSV without passing through Excel. For whatever reason saving the file as Excel CSV - UTF-8 encoding did NOT solve the issue, but this one did - converting odd characters with producing "illegal" replacements, although there are a couple I find curious.

Comment: Not sure whether it's significant enough to add as a note in somewhere more prominent, but the "direct dl" option did run into issues with the category creation part of the larger script. In short, I was still getting some failures on some categories until after switching to wp_insert_category from wp_create_category and specifically designating the category_nicename as well as the cat_name. After I've completed testing of some of your other alternatives, I may post amended code at least.

Comment: Please check the "Update" part in my answer - the function `my_fix_invalid_utf8()` is untested, though, but it should work.. (Edit: The `array_map()` call should be put right after the `foreach( $new_array as $insert_array )`, and you can also instead call the function just for certain items.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a temporary answer, but won't accept it until I've solved some new issues that arose, or were emphasized, when I expanded from 300 test rows to 20000, on the way to 100,000s, and some new characters turned up that had to be handled. If someone can provide the rest of the answer, or a superior alternative, then great, and I'll accept it instead of my own. If not, then I'll return after I've had a chance to work it out by myself.

Anyway, for particular site and **initial** data, what worked was to use `mb_convert_encoding()` in a way that remained agnostic about the source encoding, then string-replacing the bad characters I got back. So:

```
    $comment_content = mb_convert_encoding( $insert_array[4], 'HTML-ENTITIES' ) ;  
    $comment_modified = str_replace( "&#2013266066;", "&rsquo;", $comment_content ) ;
    
    $comment_data = array(
        
        'comment_author'    =>  ucfirst( $insert_array[0] ) ,
        'comment_content'   =>  $comment_modified,
        'comment_date'      =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $insert_array[5] ) ),   
        'comment_date_gmt'  =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $insert_array[5] ) ),
        'comment_post_id'   =>  '',
        'comment_meta'      => array(
        
            'db_row'    => $insert_array[6],
            'standardized_location' =>  $insert_array[7],
    
        ), 

    ) ;
```

Background: Using a function from a PHP Manual commenter 12 years ago - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php#86878 -, I was able to process the comments all into UTF-8 encoding, but got an invalid character (which renders in the output as the Unicode "replacement character" https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

However, when I processed `$comment_content` into HTML-ENTITIES, I got `&#2013266066;` back. I then ran a str_replace() on `&#2013266066;`, with `&rsquo;`, and everything processed as desired - at least for 300 rows. Unfortunately, as noted at the top, the a much larger data file turned up additional invalid characters.

Without going into the peculiar history of character sets worldwide, I'll just say that it appears that in mainly English-language character sets single and double quotes are rendered with the simple entity, but in other character sets widely in use are rendered with the other, and there are other characters common to some character sets that cause similar problems for attempts to convert them into standard English-language character sets. I still haven't had a chance to apply and compare different, possibly more efficient methods - for example, on installation configuration levels or through content filter functions - for handling the underlying issues.